# Word - Excel table caption

Tags: excel, ms-word, caption

I have added a table from Excel to Word. The table is too large for one page and is divided into two pages. Now when I add a caption, this is only displayed at the top of page 1, but nothing on page 2. How can I edit it so I can put something like

```
"Page1"
Table1: Sales
(table)
*Page2*
**++Table1: Sales (continued)++**
(table continues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Headers inplace of caption. Use a different header for the first page and yet another one for the 2nd page. Use page numbers in the format "page x of y" in the fotter to make it more accesible.

You may also make the single table as two tables. If your single table is too large, to fit in one page vertically, word will put it in 2 or more pages. This however will not result in the repeating of the caption or even the column headers. This obtion is however available in Excel where you go to page setup and select the rows and columns to repeat at the top.

When u break you single table into two tables, one for each page you can customize the caption for each table seperately. You can also than repeat the column headers.

Comment: Thank you, hmm I guess I'll split the table then. Yes, I already found out about repeating table headers. :)

Comment: I used your way, but not the solution :) I just copied my table parts so they fitted on each page and then added a caption.

Comment: You could also go in  the table properties dialogue box, select the row tab and check the "Allow row to break across pages" check box. Or you could Click in the row above which you want to split the table. Then select Table Split Table. This splits the table into two by inserting an empty paragraph between the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit of a cludge, but you can put the caption in the first row of the table itself, and turn on "Repeat as header row at top of each page".

Merge all cells and turn off borders in the first row, caption then looks like its outside the table.

Easy way to get the caption into the table is to insert it normally, then cut and paste it into the table.